# Disable uglyfying in r.js

Tags: javascript, optimization, requirejs, uglifyjs, r.js

I am looking for a way to prevent r.js (RequireJS' optimization script) from ugylyfying our JS-modules to maintain readability for debugging purposes.
I expect the script (running on Node.js by the way) to have some command line option to be passed.
Unfortunately, the documentation if this tool is rather poor.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Pass `optimize=none` on the command line to r.js, or include `optimize: "none"` in your build script.

eg:

```
({
    baseUrl: ".",
    paths: {
        jquery: "some/other/jquery"
    },
    name: "main",
    out: "main-built.js",
    optimize: "none"
})
```

See http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html for more information.

If you check [the source](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/cf9abe82/build/example.build.js#L109), you will see that the default is set to "uglify". Here are the options which are accepted:

- `uglify`: (default) uses UglifyJS to minify the code.
- `uglify2`: in version 2.1.2+. Uses UglifyJS2.
- `closure`: uses Google's Closure Compiler in simple optimization mode to minify the code. Only available if running the optimizer using Java.
- `closure.keepLines`: Same as closure option, but keeps line returns in the minified files.
- `none`: no minification will be performed.

Comment: Although it seems to ignore the command line argument but when I add it in the build-json it works fine

Comment: The command line argument is supposed to be `optimize=none`, instead of `--optimize=none` (which should show up as an edit soon in the post)