# RequireJS: namespace in development environment to avoid conflict with other AMD lib

Tags: javascript, requirejs

The project I am working on uses requireJS. Works very well, when we want to build it, we use:

```
({
  // ..
  namespace: 'projectCodeName',
  // ..
});
```

But I sometimes need to load another library that also uses requireJS, but doesn't namespace it `:(`).

I production, I don't have any issue, since my own `requirejs` is accessible on `window.projectCodeName.require()`.

But in dev, nothing works as expected.

I found I can build requireJS [without uglyfying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470521/disable-uglyfying-in-r-js), but still, it is a pity to loose file match, line numbers etc.

Can I use requireJS in development mode with a namespace. Something like:

```
<script data-namespace="projectCodeName" src="bower_components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
```

Cheers

---

EDIT:

I tried to do this manually like:

```
window.projectCodeName = window.projectCodeName || {};
window.projectCodeName.require = window.require;
window.projectCodeName.requirejs = window.requirejs;
window.projectCodeName.define = window.define;
delete require;
delete requirejs;
delete define;
```

Unfortunately the latter `delete require` doesn't work, it returns false, meaning this is a [non-configurable property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete).

I thought [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) was really good at avoiding global namespace issues, but instead it keeps bringing trouble. It is really annoying and disappointing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [multiversion support in requirejs](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#multiversion), so you can set up a context per project. This is an example from the doc page. Is this what you want?

```
var reqOne = require.config({
  context: "version1",
  baseUrl: "version1"
});

reqOne(["require", "alpha", "beta",],
function(require,   alpha,   beta) {
  log("alpha version is: " + alpha.version); //prints 1
  log("beta version is: " + beta.version); //prints 1

  setTimeout(function() {
    require(["omega"],
      function(omega) {
        log("version1 omega loaded with version: " +
             omega.version); //prints 1
      }
    );
  }, 100);
});

var reqTwo = require.config({
  context: "version2",
  baseUrl: "version2"
});

reqTwo(["require", "alpha", "beta"],
    function(require,   alpha,   beta) {
  log("alpha version is: " + alpha.version); //prints 2
  log("beta version is: " + beta.version); //prints 2

  setTimeout(function() {
    require(["omega"],
      function(omega) {
        log("version2 omega loaded with version: " +
        omega.version); //prints 2
      }
    );
  }, 100);
});
```